# R Convert NA's only after the first non-zero value

Tags: r, nan, statistics

I have a large data set which consists of a columns of IDs followed by a monthly time series for each ID.  There are frequent missing values in this set, but what I would like to do is replace all NAs after the first non-zero with a zero while leaving all the NAs before the first non-zero value as NA's.

eg.

[NA NA NA 1 2 3 NA 4 5 NA] would be changed to [NA NA NA 1 2 3 0 4 5 0]

Any help or advice you guys could offer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to do using `match()` and numeric indices:

- use `match()` to find the first occurence of a non-NA value
- use `which()` to convert the logical vector from `is.na()` to a numeric index
- use that information to find the correct positions in x

Hence:

```
x <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5,NA)
isna <- is.na(x)
nonna <- match(FALSE,isna)
id <- which(isna)
x[id[id>nonna]] <- 0
```

gives:

```
> x
 [1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  0  0  4  5  0
```

Comment: Nice, thats a really elegant solution! Would you have any advice on how to extend this to a data frame ? Ie.  The same thing only with many IDs.  When I try various different things I just get back an "new columns would leave holes after existing columns" error. Thanks, your solution has been a big help so far!

Comment: This tells me you're using `replace()` with wrong indices. It's not clear what you want. Try giving a minimal example in a new question and add the code you tried but that didn't work. Make sure you link to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method. Convert all to zeros first, then covert the first zeros back to `NA`.

```
> x <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,4,5,NA)
> x[which(is.na(x))] <- 0
### index from 1 to first element before the first element >0
> x[1:min(which(x>0))-1] <- NA
> x
 [1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  0  0  4  5  0
```

also

```
### end of vector (elements are >0)
> endOfVec <- min(which(x>0)):length(x)
> x[endOfVec][is.na(x[endOfVec])] <- 0
[1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  0  0  4  5  0
```