# Replace missing values in a time series dataset with both NA and Zero

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, missingmethodexception

I have a problem at hand.

Objective: I have a monthly time series data set which comprises of "zero's" as well as "NAs". Here Zero's are values and I want them to be changed whereas NA's are the missing values that I am looking to impute using StructTS in R.

**Data set example**

```
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
dataset[1,2]<-0
dataset[4,4] <- 0
```

Here in dataset, I just want to replace the NA with a value and let the zero's be zeros only.

After researching and reading several blogs, I used the following methods:

```
    missvalue <- function(df){
    x<-df
    x <- ts(rev(x),f=12)

    fit <- ts(rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(x))[,-2]))
    tsp(fit) <- tsp(x)  
    return(list(N=fit))
    }

    Newdata<-lapply(m,missvalue)
```

I also tried a mean technique:

```
   ##Missing Value another treatment 

    nzmean <- function(x) {
    if (all(x==0)) 0 else mean(x[x!=0])
    }
    apply(m,1,nzmean)
```

Attached are the posts I referred:

1. [R Convert NA's only after the first non-zero value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684499/r-convert-nas-only-after-the-first-non-zero-value)
2. [Interpolate missing values in a time series with a seasonal cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964255/interpolate-missing-values-in-a-time-series-with-a-seasonal-cycle)

Any help on this would be really great.

Comment: U can replace the NAs by something like this `dataset[is.na(dataset)] <- 250`. just change the 250 with a list of your values to replace.

Comment: What is your expected output of `dataset`?

Comment: I want the NA's to be replaced with either mean of the last 5 numbers or any other missing value technique. Zero's should stay as zero only.

Comment: Try any of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+replace+NA+with+mean

Comment: drmariod I have tried that as well. I replaced all the NAs with "999999999" but that didnt help me solve the issue at hand. I don't know how to proceed post that.

Comment: Pierre I have looked into that post. The only difference between that dataset and mine is that it does not have zeros. If I only had NAs, the task would have been simpler.

Comment: What do you mean by last 5 numbers? I mean, the data is two dimensional. You can define the mean and sd per column and replace the NAs by normal distributed random numbers based on column (or row) mean. There are tons of ways and I guess we need more information on the data type.

Comment: ok Pierre I would go through it again and see if i find a solution.

Comment: Mariod I have a time series dataset where my rows are months and columns are store numbers. For each store at a month level, I have the sales value. Here some stores opened late and hence the sales for that period is zero which is ok. whereas there are some stores where values are missing.

Answer (score 3):

`na.approx` is a useful function from the package 'zoo'. It will use several methods to approximate missing values in the data set. Search `?na.approx` for more information on parameter options and applications. It will focus on `NA` entries and will leave zeroes untouched. Hope that helps.

```
library(zoo)
na.approx(dataset)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.0    0    4    1    1
[2,]  5.0    1    3    5    1
[3,]  3.0    2    4    2    1
[4,]  3.5    2    2    0    1
[5,]  4.0    5    2    4    1
```

**Data**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    4    1    1
[2,]    5    1    3    5   NA
[3,]    3    2    4    2   NA
[4,]   NA    2    2    0    1
[5,]    4    5    2    4    1
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. This is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the imputeTS package here (I am the maintainer). Makes life really easy for this task.
(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/index.html)

Offers several algorithms like imputation with mean, median, linear interpolation, spline interpolation, kalman smoothing, ...

Here one example:

```
library(imputeTS)
dataset[ ,1] <- na.kalman(dataset[ ,1])
```

Another one:

```
   dataset[ ,1] <- na.interpolation(dataset[ ,1])
```

Another one:

```
   dataset[ ,1] <- na.mean(dataset[ ,1])
```

Another one:

```
   dataset[ ,1] <- na.locf(dataset[ ,1])
```

The only downside is, the package does not allow a data.frame as input, so one would have to loop through the columns seperatly.
(but on the positive side you could also use different algorithms for different columns)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have found that na.seadec replaces zero values as well as NA values.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for reporting this. This actually shouldn't happen...Already found the root cause... trying to fix this as soon as possible

Comment: @CameronNemo the version with the fix is now on CRAN.